# How to convert a list into separate arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm a beginner so go easy on me please. I have the following list and want to convert it into 3 separate arrays. How do I do that?

```
    [[-20.2, -40.5, -9.8], [167.3, 155.5, 135.7, 108.8, 76.0, 39.0], [-22.7, -22.3, -21.9, -21.4, -20.8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use iterable unpacking and the built-in `array` module:

```
import array

big_list = [[-20.2, -40.5, -9.8], [167.3, 155.5, 135.7, 108.8, 76.0, 39.0], [-22.7, -22.3, -21.9, -21.4, -20.8]]
arr1, arr2, arr3 = [array.array('d', sublist) for sublist in big_list]

print(arr1)
# array('d', [-20.2, -40.5, -9.8])
```

If you want to extract the three *lists* (as opposed to arrays), just use iterable unpacking:

```
l1, l2, l3 = [[-20.2, -40.5, -9.8], [167.3, 155.5, 135.7, 108.8, 76.0, 39.0], [-22.7, -22.3, -21.9, -21.4, -20.8]]
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. How would the code look like if the number of elements in the list can vary, so that you dont know, that you need to generate exactly 3 arrays (in my example it could be more or less than 3)

Comment: This cannot be done. A variable number of elements can only be stored in a collection (like a list). Creating a variable number of variables, as would be needed to extract `n` sublists, is not possible

Answer (score 0):

for Assing the value of the array elements you can just give value to your array and make 3 value for each elements. Like this:

```
x = [[-20.2, -40.5, -9.8], [167.3, 155.5, 135.7, 108.8, 76.0, 39.0], [-22.7, -22.3, -21.9, -21.4, -20.8]]
a, b, c = x
```

if you print `a` you see that the first element of x array and other value such as `b` or `c`